# How to delete a row in a table using Django?

Tags: sql, django

I want to delete a row from a table in the shell provided by Django. I am running the command `Birthdays.objects.delete()` but it's not working and gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`Birthday.objects` returns a Queryset (a django dictionnary).

You need to ask for a specific object. For example:

`Birthday.objects.filter(id=1).delete()`

Documentation :  [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)